# Floating Point Textures in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I've been trying to figure out how to use float textures in GLES2. [The API Reference](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/glTexImage2D.xml) says that only unsigned bytes and shorts can be used, but I've seen people saying it is supported elsewhere.

I could use `GL_LUMINANCE` as the texture format but that only gets me one float value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2.0, floating-point textures are only supported if the implementation exports the [`OES_texture_float`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) extension. Note that this extension only allows nearest filtering within a texture level, and no filtering between texture levels. This restriction is loosened by the presence of [`OES_texture_float_linear`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float_linear.txt). Another potential caveat is that the presence of `OES_texture_float` does not require that the implementation support rendering to floating-point textures with framebuffer objects.

What are you trying to do with float textures?

Comment: I'm storing some position information. So there would be a fragment shader that does some calculations (particle motion) and renders to a framebuffer which is fed into another shader (render). The thing is, i need float precision.

Comment: On my implementation (coding for iOS) the keys were "GL_OES_texture_float" and "GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear"