# Implementing sparse matrix construction and multiplication in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, matrix

I have googled around but havnt found an answer that suits me for OpenGL.

I want to construct a sparse matrix with a single diagonal and around 9 off-diagonals. These diagonals arent necessarily next to the main diagonal and they wrap around. Each diagonal is an image in row-major format i.e. a vector of size NxM.

The size of the matrix is (NxM)x(NxM)

My question is as follows:
After some messing around with the math I have arrived at the basic units of my operation. It involves a pixel by pixel multiplication of two images (WITHOUT limiting the value of the result i.e. so it can be above 1 or below 0), storing the resulting image and then adding a bunch of the resulting images (SAME as above).

How can I multiply and add images on a pixel by pixel basis in OpenGL? Is it easier in 1.1 or 2.0? Will use of textures cause hard maxing of the results to between 0 and 1? Will this maximize the use of the gpu cores?

Comment: Why do you think using OpenGL is the best tool for this problem?

Comment: I dont actually think its the best tool for the problem but then the question is what is the best tool. Id say OpenCL but its not supported on mobile platforms yet. Then I might say Cuda but that limits this to NVidia hardware. Then I arrive at OpenGL and even thats limited by value clamping. Maybe Im missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to store values outside the `[0-1]` range you would have to use floating point textures. There is no support in OpenGL ES 1.1 and for OpenGL ES 2.0 it is an optional extension (See other  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937535/floating-point-textures-in-opengl-es-2-0)).

In case your implementation supports it you could then write a fragment program to do the required math.

In OpenGL ES 1.1 you could use the `glTexEnv` call to set up how the pixels from different texture units are supposed to be combined. You could then use "modulate" or "add" to multiply/add the values. The result would be clamped to `[0,1]` range though.

Comment: Thanks. Thats definitely useful. I havnt started learning OpenGL ES 2.0 yet but im guessing thats the way forward. If I use fragment shaders can I achieve multiplication and addition without value clamping?

Comment: i.e can i define arrays in graphics memory and then just copy data from the cpu to those arrays?

Comment: You would have to use textures for that.

Comment: Couldnt I upload arrays of vertices and then in a fragment program add them and multiply them and do whatever I need to do and then somehow pull that data back from graphics memory?