# Using GL_R32F texture with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an array of floats which i want to transfer to a fragment shader in Android Studio using OpenGL ES 2. As far as i can see, the only provided "internalFormat" values (in the GLES20 class) are three or four component RGB or RGBA and GL_R32F is unsupported it seems. How can i transfer a float array to a fragment shader as a texture in GLES20?

edit:
To add some detail, i'm running a fluid simulation which outputs an array of density values for each point in the grid. These values are between 0 and 1 and would be ideally transferred as-is for speed. It [may be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937535/floating-point-textures-in-opengl-es-2-0) i need to convert the array to an integer format though.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i transfer a float array to a fragment shader as a texture in GLES20?

Directly, you can't.

You can try packing some form of higher dynamic range value into multiple color channels of an RGBA8 unorm texture and then reconstructing the value in the shader, but it's not going to be free ...